# How to make duplicate sequences by group

Tags: r, sequence, repeat

I would like to make groups of data into sequence

```
A B
1 dog
1 cat
1 fish
1 kimchi
1 salsa
1 pizza
2 dog
2 cat
2 fish
2 kimchi
2 salsa
2 pizza
```

I would like the same sequence to 204 times
currently used rep and each function but doesn't seem to work :(

thanks in advance~

Comment: that makes it so each sequence is added by sequence of numbers.

Comment: Just use `order`after that: `eg <- expand.grid(A = 1:3, B = c('dog','cat','fish')); eg[order(eg$A),]`

Comment: Another option: `tidyr::crossing(A = 1:3, B = c('dog','cat','fish'))`

Comment: wow it works! thanks

Comment: actually then the order is in alphabetical order

Comment: `eg <- expand.grid(A = 1:3, B = factor(c('dog','cat','fish'))); eg[order(eg$A),]`